# ¿Por qué el socket no envía el mensaje correctamente usando socket.io?

Tags: python, socket.io

Estoy trabajando con socketio y tengo un sistema con namespaces que funciona correctamente cuando llegan datos de un servidor, pero para poder hacer pruebas tengo que enviar a un namespace especifico data, lo cual intente hacer pero sucedieron cosas raras. lo cual después de muchos intentos llegue a lo siguiente:
cree esta clase en python para poder hacer la conexión y el envío de datos

```
class socketClient():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sio = socketio.AsyncClient()
    
    async def connect(self):
        await self.sio.connect("{}://{}:{}".format("http", "localhost", 80), namespaces=['/acumulatedMetrics'])

    async def emit(self, event, data):
        await self.sio.emit(event, data, namespace='/acumulatedMetrics')

    async def disconnect(self):
        await self.sio.disconnect()
```

y para utilizarla esta el siguiente codigo:

```
async def run():
    sk=socketClient()
    await sk.connect()
    await sk.emit("report",b"esto es un mensaje")
    await sk.disconnect()

asyncio.run(run())
```

El problema no es que se conecte o desconecte, sino que el dato que esta enviando no llega al namespace que corresponde, solo hace la conexión y desconexión.
**Pero** y aquí es donde viene lo extraño, agrego un "await print("algo")" al final de la función **emit** si envía en mensaje correspondiente y el código después arroja error ya que "print" es una función sin retorno y await no se puede utilizar en este tipo de funciones, entonces el código deja de funcionar.

por cierto, este es el codigo del name space que me estoy conectando:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", async_mode='eventlet', logger=False, engineio_logger=False, max_http_buffer_size=1e8)
class acumulatedMetrics(Namespace):
    def on_connect(self):
        print(f"Connect acumulatedMetrics sid: {request.sid}")

    def on_report(self,data):
        print(f"llego algo en acumulatedMetrics")
        print(data)
        socketio.emit('distribution', data, namespace='/NLP_visualization')

    def on_disconnect(self):
        print(f"Disconnect acumulatedMetrics sid: {request.sid}")  

socketio.on_namespace(acumulatedMetrics("/acumulatedMetrics"))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.info(f"Server start")
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, port=80, host="0.0.0.0", log_output=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar un mensaje a un namespace específico en Socket.io, puedes usar la función send en lugar de emit. La función emit se utiliza para enviar mensajes a todos los clientes conectados al namespace, mientras que la función send solo se enviará al cliente especificado por el identificador de sesión (sid).

Por lo tanto, para enviar un mensaje a un cliente específico en un namespace, puedes usar algo como lo siguiente:

```
await self.sio.send(event, data, sid, namespace='/acumulatedMetrics')
```

Si deseas enviar un mensaje a todos los clientes conectados al namespace, puedes usar la función emit como lo estás haciendo actualmente.

```
await self.sio.emit(event, data, namespace='/acumulatedMetrics')
```

Además, es importante tener en cuenta que la función print en Python no es una función asíncrona, por lo que no puedes utilizar await con ella. En su lugar, puedes usar la función logging.info para escribir mensajes en el registro. Esta función es asíncrona y se puede usar con await.

```
import logging

logging.info("algo")
```

Espero que esto ayude. Si tienes alguna pregunta, no dudes en hacérmela saber.